# cleaned_data.get('department') returning <company.models.Service> in django

Tags: django

Hei,

I am really clueless on this error I am getting. Basically, I need to display list of service a loggedin user can register clients to. Now, a user can have the right to register to all services in the company or to a single service. So, I came up with this in my forms.py file:

```
    def __init__(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        super(NewPatientForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        receptionistFor=receptionisttype(request)
        self.receptionistFor=receptionistFor
        if receptionistFor==0:
            services=Service.objects.filter(serviceNature='Clientel',kind='internal',active='yes').only('id','name')
    else:
        services=Service.objects.filter(active='yes',serviceNature='Clientel',kind='internal',pk=receptionistFor).only('id','name')
     self.fields['department']=forms.ModelChoiceField(required=True,queryset=services,widget=forms.Select())
```

Where receptionisttype is a method in a package, which is working fine. I see only allowed services per logged in user in my template through this:

```
{% render_field form.department|add_class:"form-control select2" %}
```

Now my problem is when reading back the value of the HTML element in my forms.py clean method, I get a model instance:

```
    def clean(self):
    '''
    Grouped cleaning
    '''


         cleaned_data=super().clean()

         selectedDepartment=cleaned_data.get('department')
         print(str(type(selectedDepartment))) 
         #gives <class 'company.models.Service'>
```

What am I doing wrong exactly? I get values of other controls that are not created in **init** pretty well except this one.

Comment: What makes you think something is wrong? That seems to be entirely what is expected. What would you want to be different?

Comment: Oh ok Daniel. I was expecting the values 115, 301 etc that were the values in the generated select element. But i guess i was wrong. Thanks.